# replace the timezone offset from DATE javascript

Tags: javascript, angular

if I get UTC date below
2012-04-17T15:40+05:00 ====result i am expecting======>>> 2012-04-17T15:40+08:00

I don't want to convert I just want to replace the timezone offset

Comment: Do you have the option to use momentjs? https://momentjs.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're talking about string manipulation, you can do something like this:

```js
function replaceTimezoneOffset(dateTime: string, newOffset: string): string {
  return `${dateTime.split('+')[0]}${newOffset}`;
}
```

And you can use it like this:

```js
  const newDate = replaceTimezoneOffset('2012-04-17T15:40+05:00', '+08:00');

  console.log({newDate}); // {newDate: '2012-04-17T15:40+08:00'}
```